# Flot: combine stacked bars and line in one chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to combine stacked bars and a line chart in one flot plot.

The problem I'm facing is, that the line data also gets stacked. Which means the data for the first point (`line.data[0]`) will be plotted as `15` but I would like it to be `5`.

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/derkinzi/eor5ngjd/

It works when setting `stack: null` but I need the stacks. Also giving the line it's own yaxis doesn't solve the problem. (change line 90 to: `yaxis: 2`)

How can I amend the code so `line.data` get's it's independent plotting with an independent yaxis?

Basically I need this but with stacked bars: http://jsfiddle.net/derkinzi/eor5ngjd/11/

This is my dataset:

```
var stack1 = {
    label: 'stack1',
    data: [
      [1, 6],
      [2, 3],
      [4, 5],
      [4, 3],
      [5, 4]
    ],
    bars: bar_options
  };
  var stack2 = {
    label: 'stack2',
    data: [
      [1, 4],
      [2, 4],
      [3, 4],
      [4, 4],
      [5, 4]
    ],
    bars: bar_options
  };
  var line = {
    label: 'line',
    data: [
      [1, 5],
      [2, 15],
      [3, 15],
      [4, 15],
      [5, 20]
    ],
    lines: line_options,
    yaxis: 1,
    points: {
      radius: 5,
      show: true
    },
  };
  var dataset = [stack1, stack2, line];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As describes in the [stack plugin](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js), you can specify the `stack` option per data series, so in your case do this:

```
var stack1 = {
    //...
    stack: true,
};
var stack2 = {
    //...
    stack: true,
};
var line = {
    //...
    stack: false,
    //...
};
```

Also, when you define multiple axes, use the `yaxes` property, not `yaxis`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eor5ngjd/13/)

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charme. It tried adding stack before but always in the original object: `series: { stack: true}`which didn't work obviously... :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that there are _both_ `yaxes` & `yaxis` properties!